# dwr send data to particular client only

Tags: java, javascript, dwr

I have tried the dwr sample chat app, I think the code below sends data to all connected clients.

```
Collection pages = wctx.getScriptSessionsByPage(currentPage);
    for (Iterator it = pages.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
    {
        ScriptSession otherSession = (ScriptSession) it.next();
        otherSession.addScript(script);
    }
```

If i am wright, how could I send the data to a particular client only, using JSESSIONID??
A simple example may hel.

Thanks and regards

Comment: otherSession.getId() should return your JSESSIONID. Check that id against the Http session id and it should work.

Comment: Hi. I am always getting a new ID, how shld i compare with old one?